# Physical button interacting with tkinter button widget

Tags: button, tkinter, gpio

I'm making an app to run with my Raspberry Pi with Tkinter GUI. The app allready runs well. Now I want to use 2 physical buttons wired to GPIOS that interact with two of the buttons widgets I have in the app. Thanks to helpers in forums I found the way to do it as You can see in the code. But now I need to disabled in some way the physical button in order to avoid accidental push meanwhile the scripts run, as I can easly do with the widgets. I've been googling a lot but I din not found any example of whaT i need. Can some one give me orientation about the method to obtain this. Thanks in advance.

```
from Tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
root = Tk()
root.geometry("320x480")
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

shootdelay = 12 #12
shootinterval = 7#7
shootnumber = 5#12
videodelay = 3
selft = 5
newset = 0
endvideo = 5
intertext = "(D:" + str(shootdelay) + ")(I:" + str(shootinterval) +   ")(T:" + str(shootnumber) + ")"

flagselftim = 0  
flagvideo = 0 
videosetmode = 0 
flagsetings = 0 
flagcancel = 0  
flagnewset = 0 
secDelay = shootdelay
secInterv = shootinterval
secSelftim = selft
secvideo = videodelay
remainshots = shootnumber
secshoots = shootnumber - 1
seccompte = 0
readyshoots = 


class intervalometer:

def __init__(self, master):

    self.textBox = Text(root, height=1, width=1, relief=SUNKEN, font=('arial narrow', 17, 'normal'), bg="green",
                        fg="white")
    self.textBox.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=3, pady=2, sticky=NSEW)
    self.textBox.insert(END, "READY")

    self.botshoot = Button(root, width=18, font=('arial narrow', 19, 'normal'), text="START",
                           activebackground="#00dfdf")
    self.botshoot.grid(row=4, rowspan=2, column=0, columnspan=2, ipady=15, pady=2, sticky=NSEW)
    self.botshoot.configure(command=self.start)



    self.botStop = Button(root, heigh=2, font=('arial', 18, 'normal'), text="STOP/RESET", activebackground="red")
    self.botStop.grid(row=13, rowspan=3, column=0, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
    self.botStop.configure(state=DISABLED, command=self.stop)

    self.botQuit = Button(root, width=3, font=('arial', 18, 'normal'), text="QUIT", activebackground="red",
                          state=NORMAL)
    self.botQuit.grid(row=13, rowspan=3, column=1, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
    self.botQuit.configure(command=self.closewindow)



    GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.RISING, callback=self.start, bouncetime=200)


def start(self, *args, **kwargs):
    global flagselftim

    self.count = 0
    self.cancel_id = None
    self.botshoot.configure(state=DISABLED)

    self.botStop.configure(state=NORMAL)
    self.botQuit.configure(state=DISABLED)


    self.start_shoot_delay()



def stop(self):
    global secDelay
    global secSelftim
    global selft
    global flagvideo
    global videosetmode
    global secvideo
    global remainshots
    global secInterv
    global readyshoots
    flagvideo = 0
    videosetmode = 0
    secDelay = shootdelay
    secInterv = shootinterval
    secvideo = videodelay
    selft = 5
    secSelftim = selft
    remainshots = shootnumber
    readyshoots = 1
    if self.cancel_id is not None:
        self.textBox.after_cancel(self.cancel_id)
        self.cancel_id = None
        self.textBox.insert(END, 0)
        self.textBox.delete("1.0", END)
        self.botshoot.configure(text="START")
        self.botshoot.configure(state=NORMAL)

        self.botStop.configure(state=DISABLED)
        self.botQuit.configure(state=NORMAL)

        self.textBox.insert(END, "READY")
        self.textBox.configure(font=('arial narrow', 17, 'normal'), bg="green", fg="white")



def closewindow(self):
    root.destroy()

def start_shoot_delay(self):
    global secDelay

    if secDelay > 9:
        contador = "   " + str(secDelay)
    else:
        contador = "    " + str(secDelay)

    self.textBox.delete("1.0", END)
    self.textBox.configure(font=('arial narrow', 17, 'normal'), bg="red", fg="white")
    self.botshoot.configure(state=DISABLED)
    if self.count < shootdelay:
        self.count += 1
        self.textBox.insert(END, contador)
        self.cancel_id = self.textBox.after(1000, self.start_shoot_delay)
        secDelay -= 1
    else:
        self.count = 0
        secDelay = shootdelay
        self.start_shoot_interval()


def start_shoot_interval(self):
    global secInterv
    if remainshots == shootnumber:
        self.start_shootings()
    else:
        if secInterv > 9:
            contador = "   " + str(secInterv)
        else:
            contador = "    " + str(secInterv)

        self.textBox.delete("1.0", END)
        self.textBox.configure(font=('arial narrow', 17, 'normal'), bg="red", fg="white")

        if self.count < shootinterval:
            self.count += 1
            self.textBox.insert(END, contador)
            self.cancel_id = self.textBox.after(1000, self.start_shoot_interval)
            secInterv -= 1
        else:
            self.count = 0
            secInterv = shootinterval
            self.start_shootings()


def start_shootings(self):
    global remainshots
    global videosetmode
    global readyshoots
    global secSelftim
    global selft
    remainshots -=1
    if secSelftim <5:
        txtremain = "SHOOTING = " + str(1) + "/" + str(1)
    else:
        txtremain = "REMAINING = " + str(remainshots) + "/" + str(shootnumber)

    print  "BEEP shoot nr",readyshoots, "av", shootnumber


    readyshoots +=1
    if remainshots >0:
        self.start_shoot_interval()
    else:
        print "BEEP-BEEP-BEEP : end of roll"
        self.etstatus.configure(text="END OF ROLL")
        root.update_idletasks()
        root.after(500)
        readyshoots = 1
        selft = 5
        self.textBox.insert(END, "READY")
        self.textBox.configure(font=('arial narrow', 17, 'normal'), bg="green", fg="white")
        self.botshoot.configure(state=NORMAL)
        self.botStop.configure(state=DISABLED)
        self.botQuit.configure(state=NORMAL)
        remainshots = shootnumber

intervalometer(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is even an issue since the start method should lock up the entire program, including the input from the button. If the button detection is in it's own thread or something, you could just add a check. The easiest thing to check is the tk Button state:

```
def start(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.botshoot['state'] == DISABLED:
        print 'already running'
        return # abort this method
    self.botshoot.configure(state=DISABLED)
    # etc ...
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, you are right , I send a example I use to test the physical button. The problem appears in the full script I wrote. As the button is always active if I press again when the function is running the scrip start to do wrong things an be fool. I put the full script now

Comment: sorry, I want to publish the script but I'm not able to do it... I'll try to make a resum. Thanks

Comment: I edit my question and put the full script, As you can see when the function start_shoot_delay runs it's continuosly looking for a event of the botStop button widget that stot the script and put all to initial values, That's why a accidental press of the physical button can be detected. That's the reason that I want to disable this physical button until function has finish.

Comment: OK, so I see you used `after` instead of a new thread to keep the method from locking up the whole program. My answer still works in this case.

Comment: Great Jonathan, Now is running as I need it. Thanks a lot. I was getting krazy looking for a solution. Thanks again for your help.